# Bootstrap Styles 404 in Angular

Tags: angular

Got a weird scenario with the Boostrap css file returning a 404.

It is just a simple Angular "quick-start" style app which I created with the Angular CLI. I added Bootstrap to the package.json and installed it using `npm update`.

The index file is a very simple and includes the following link element in the head:
`<link href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

The bootstrap.min.css class does exist at that location.

I then run the app using `ng serve --port 3000 --open`

No styling appears in the page rendered and in the Chrome dev tools (in the console) there is the red error text informing me that
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
 :3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

However, if I click the Sources tab of the dev tools, the bootstrap.min.css class is right there, as I'd expect it.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the stylesheet inside the `styles` array of your `.angular-cli.json` configuration:

```
{ 
  ...,
  "apps": [
    {
       ...,
       "styles": [
         "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

If you have your `root` in the configuration at the `src` folder for instance, you should add `../` in front of your style url

Comment: Had a feeling it was something like that. The .. did it too. Now the style shows up. Weird thing is, I still get the red 404 error in the dev tools. Even though Bootstrap is there and working.

Comment: Remove it from your `index.html` ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre. With the speed Angular is moving, the learning materials are fast becoming out of date. Hence my confusion. My book is already partly obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your angular.cli.json to add your third party styles.

```
  "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
```